# Posts list in custom taxonomy

Tags: posts, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have someting like this:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'kosmetyki_dystrybutor'); 
$terms_ids = [];

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $terms_ids[] = $term->term_id;
}

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'kosmetyki',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'kosmetyki_dystrybutor',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array($term->term_id) 
        )
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
?>
   //here posts

<?php endwhile;
endif;?>
```

But not working. I need posts from taxonomy 'kosmetyki_dystrybutor'. Each 'dystrybutor' need own posts list. What I do wrong? Thx for help :)

Comment: 1) Where is `$term` coming from? 2) Have you tried anything where `//here posts` is? `the_post()` doesn't do anything on its own.

Comment: Where is `$term` coming from?

Comment: I add full code. In //here posts I need posts with <?php the_title(); ?> and <?php the_content(); ?>

Answer (score 0):

`$term` isn't being set anywhere in your code. You're putting IDs into `$terms_ids`, but then in your query you're using `$term->term_id`. `$term` doesn't exist outside of the `foreach`. You need to be passing `$terms_ids` directly into `terms`:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'kosmetyki_dystrybutor'); 
$terms_ids = [];

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $terms_ids[] = $term->term_id;
}

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'kosmetyki',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'kosmetyki_dystrybutor',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $terms_ids, 
        )
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Thx, but the problem still exist :(

Comment: Maybe all my code is wrong? I need list like here czytamyetykiety.pl/manufacturer/babybel/ but with taxonomy not category.

Comment: Where is this code? `get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'kosmetyki_dystrybutor'); ` will get the `kosmetyki_dystrybutor` terms of the current post. Is it within the loop, and in a post that would have terms in the `kosmetyki_dystrybutor` taxonomy?

Comment: Hmm, the code is on "dystrybutor" page like this one czytamyetykiety.pl/kosmetyki_dystrybutor/costasy

Comment: I choose "dystrybutor" here czytamyetykiety.pl/dystrybutorzy and next step is dystrybutor page where I need list of posts for selected "dystrybutor"